# How to remove same elements with different orders in a list?

Tags: python

For example, I'm working on a method that given a certain size "**k**", and an integer "**n**" I can generate subsets from **{1...n}** with "**k**" length.

This is my code so far:

```
def combinations(k,lista,comb):
    if(len(comb)==k):
        print(comb)
    else:
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            combinations(k,lista,comb + str(lista[i]))
def starter(n,k):
    lista = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        lista.append(i)
    combinations(k,lista,"")

starter(5,3)
```

The output of `starter(5,3)` is:

```
111
112
113
114
115
121
122
123
124
125
131
132
133
134
135
.
.
.
545
551
552
553
554
555
```

My problem is that it is repetitive, as you see I have 545 and 554 in the output(and 455;not shown), while in this case ordering shouldn't matter, therefore I should keep either 545 or 554 or 455. I also have 332 in the output as well as 323 and 233, these three are considered "duplicates" and I need to keep only one.

How can  my code be modified to filter for this?

Edit: in my code "k" was "m", I fixed it to avoid misconceptions.

Edit2: I do understand that I can use itertools, but I am trying to solve everything(for now) without depending on libraries or packages.

Comment: You should probably just use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) from Python standard lib.

Comment: I recently started learning programming therefore I strongly try to search for solutions that don't require me to depend on a library..

Comment: @NathKnight, in that case, there is a "Roughly equivalent to" part for this function. You might check out that in the above link.

Comment: @brentertainer `itertools.combinations()` will not have `545`, `554` or `455` to begin with, so it is definitely not a viable solution!

Comment: @NathKnight if your goal is to learn the underlying algorithms behind standard functions, you should probably look for a book on that. If it is to code just *without libraries* you'll probably have a hard time getting help. If you want to get to know why your specific implementation does not work the way you intended, you have to state this more clearly in the question, be more precise on expected and actual inputs and outputs.

Comment: @norok2 Those are not subsets/combinations.

Comment: @brentertainer From OP "I also have 332 in the output as well as 323 and 233, these three are considered "duplicates" and **I need to keep only one**."

Comment: @NathKnight Please read what norok2 wrote. Is `545` a valid output (since it has 5 twice, it is not technically a subset). This is the difference between `itertools.combinations` and `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use rather itertools functions for that. Does this function work for you?

```
from itertools import combinations
list(combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], 3))
```

More info on itertools functions here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertool-functions

Comment: It does work but I just started learning programming, I am trying to figure out how to solve such problems without depending on libraries. (in order to grasp the concepts fully)

Comment: I think you are doing the right thing! I also used to do it. I think that for avoiding repetitions what you can do is to put an if statement to print `comb` only if there the numbers are distinct

Answer (score 1):

I've used your code and made one modification to reach your solution. I'm sorting the values and storing it in a `set`.
Sorting the values will ensure that the values `545, 554 or 455` all get sorted to `455`. A `set` cannot contain duplicate values which means it'll only be added once. This does not reduce the time complexity of your algorithm because it does not generate less values, it simply does not add duplicate values and only the unique values are stored.

```py
values = set()


def combinations(k, lista, comb):
    if(len(comb) == k):
        # print(comb)
        value = ''.join(sorted(comb))
        values.add(value)
    else:
        for i in range(len(lista)):
            combinations(k, lista, comb + str(lista[i]))


def starter(n, k):
    lista = []
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        lista.append(i)
    combinations(k, lista, "")


starter(5, 3)
print(values)
```

Output:

```
{'122', '245', '145', '355', '111', '235', '223', '233', '113', '224', '144', '333', '134', '112', '445', '125', '255', '225', '155', '234', '345', '123', '444', '455', '222', '115', '344', '133', '114', '335', '124', '334', '135', '244', '555'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution that comes to my mind is mapping these numbers to a dictionary, where every digit is the key (1,2,3,...,9) and the values is the count of each digit in the given number. This way you're not taking into account the order of the digits but rather the number of times they appear in a certain number.

You just have to write a function that takes an integer as an input, iterate over it by transforming it into a string and then count each digit into a dictionary.

```
>>> n = 1233657
>>> digits = [int(d) for d in str(n)]           
>>> digits
[1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 5, 7]
>>> digit_count = dict.fromkeys(digits, 0)
for d in digits:
... digit_count[d] += 1
... 
>>> digit_count
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}
```

You'll have a dictionary with all combinations of numbers as keys and the representation explained before as values. Then you just have to group the different numbers that map to the same dictionary and choose one given your desired criteria.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times when recursion is involved, I like to keep track of the state in an outer function and use a nested/inner function to actually perform the recursion. Here, the state consists of the level (between 0 and k - 1), a stack, and the max yielded stack (to ensure no duplicates as you asked.)

With replacement:

```
def my_combinations_with_replacement(n, k):

    stack = list()
    maxstack = tuple()
    d = 0

    def _helper():
        nonlocal d, maxstack, stack
        for i in range(n):
            stack.append(i)
            if len(stack) == k:
                if tuple(sorted(stack)) > maxstack:
                    maxstack = tuple(sorted(stack))
                    yield maxstack
            else:
                d += 1
                yield from _helper()
                d -= 1
            stack.pop()

    return [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in _helper()]
```

Without replacement:

```
def my_combinations(n, k):

    stack = list()
    maxstack = tuple()
    d = 0

    def _helper():
        nonlocal d, maxstack, stack
        for i in range(d, n):
            if i not in stack:
                stack.append(i)
                if len(stack) == k:
                    if tuple(sorted(stack)) > maxstack:
                        maxstack = tuple(sorted(stack))
                        yield maxstack
                else:
                    d += 1
                    yield from _helper()
                    d -= 1
                stack.pop()

    return [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in _helper()]
```

Output:

```
>>> my_combinations_with_replacement(5, 3)
['000', '001', '002', '003', '004', '011', '012', '013', '014', '022', '023',
 '024', '033', '034', '044', '111', '112', '113', '114', '122', '123', '124',
 '133', '134', '144', '222', '223', '224', '233', '234', '244', '333', '334',
 '344', '444']
>>> my_combinations(5, 3)
['012', '013', '014', '023', '024', '034', '123', '124', '134', '234']
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the standard library is a great place to look for info.
There, the documentation reports many *equivalent* implementation in plain Python of the available functions like [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

These are significantly more efficient than the solution proposed so far in this question.